# Do I have to collect my luggage on connecting flights into Korea?

Tags: transit, luggage, south-korea, icn

I am flying SEA-ICN-DEL and am using Delta for the first leg and Asiana for the second. Would I be required to take my luggage through customs in ICN or will they transfer it through for both the let to India and to USA and I will not have to go through Korea customs?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Are you flying on a single ticket, or are your Delta and Asiana flights on separate bookings?

Comment: I am using Chase Ultimate Rewards site to book. Since this is my first time booking, I am not sure if they will give me a single PNR. The flights are not codeshare though.

Comment: I think he won't flight in a single ticket since DL would prefer connecting with KE instead of OZ

Comment: @Danh It isn't a DL revenue booking. If Chase Ultimate Rewards are doing it, I would have thought it would be a through-ticket.

Comment: It is complicated since DL and OZ belong to different alliances. I don't have a Korea visa (required for Indians) and so it would make it complicated if I have to come out and collect the bag. Even so I would prefer if they would check-in everything through and I didn't have to collect my bags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delta has an interline agreement for ticketing and baggage with Asiana. See: https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/gb/en/policy-library/reservations-and-ticketing/interline-electronic-ticketing-agreements--iet-.html This will cover your baggage, you need to ask at check-in to have your bags checked through to DEL.

Second get both boarding passes at check-in in SEA. They may say to you you need collect second boarding pass at Transfers gate (airside) in Korea. In which case go to the Asiana transfers counter at ICN. You do not need to clear customs/immigration to transfer At ICN.